# Form loading blank page and failing to send email after submission?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have just put everything online for my site, I have set everything up to what I think is correct.. but for some reason after the form has submitted, it just loads the 'send_form_email.php' page, giving the website visitor a blank page.. also I don't seem to be getting the emails sent to my inbox.. I can't figure out where I have gone wrong.. I'm guessing with the HTML?

Here is the HTML code for the form, let me know if you need to see the entire web page html:

```
    <!-- form -->

            <form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
             <fieldset>
                <legend class="lined">Pre-Register for free!</legend>

                <label for="pname">Name</label>
                <input name="pname" id="pname" value="" type="text">

                <label for="pemail">Email</label>
                <input name="pemail" id="pemail" value="" type="text">

                <label for="company">Business Name</label>
                <input name="company" id="company" value="" type="text">

                <label for="comment">Where do you offer your services?</label>
                <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>

              </fieldset>    
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form><!-- /form -->
```

And here is the PHP code (file name send_form_email.php);

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pemail'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = 'info@whichpt.com';
$email_subject = 'Pre-Registration Submission';


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo 'We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ';
    echo 'These errors appear below.<br /><br />';
    echo $error.'<br /><br />';
    echo 'Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />';
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['pname']) ||
    !isset($_POST['pemail']) ||
    !isset($_POST['company']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$pname = $_POST['pname']; // required
$pemail = $_POST['pemail']; // required
$company = $_POST['company']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = '';
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$pemail)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = '/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/';
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$pname)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The location of services information you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = 'Form details below.\n\n';

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array('content-type','bcc:','to:','cc:','href');
  return str_replace($bad,'',$string);
}

$email_message .= 'Name: '.clean_string($pname).'\n';
$email_message .= 'Email: '.clean_string($pemail).'\n';
$email_message .= 'Business: '.clean_string($company).'\n';
$email_message .= 'Comments: '.clean_string($comments).'\n';


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$pemail.'\r\n'.
'Reply-To: '.$pemail.'\r\n' .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);` You're suppressing the error on your mail function. How are you supposed to debug it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$pemail."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$pemail."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

You are mixing up concatenation .. For example:
`$headers = 'From: '.$pemail."\r\n".` should be `$headers = 'From: '.$pemail.'\r\n'.`

Shoot for readability to help you with debugging, at the very least. But see Alexander's answer to make sure that you can eval into your if statement first.

Comment: Sure you can, as long as you match them up, which it looks like he does. It's confusing and difficult to read, but that doesn't mean you *can't* do it.

Comment: @Blake, how can you assert something like that with a straight face?

Comment: Okay, it's not best practice to. There are a lot of things in there that I would be grumpy at a programmer for. Readability is important, especially if it's not just you working on a project. But you can be your own worst enemy in future changes as well.

Comment: Hey

So i've followed Alexander's advice and also yours Blake and have tidied up the code, I now get a server error?

Can someone check out the website and let me know where I have gone wrong?

Its: [link]http://www.whichpt.com/index.html
Form: [link]http://www.whichpt.com/send_form_email.php

Comment: I have updated it, have I missed something? Sorry if being dim.. been a long day. haha

Comment: I mean edit your question to replace your new send_form_email.php source code.

Comment: Change line `$string_exp = '/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/';` to `$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";` The ' in the regex string is causing it to break. Or escape the inner '.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `$_POST['pemail']`

```
if(isset($_POST['pemail'])) { ... }
```

instead.